# Registration form in java

Tags: java, derby, javadb

Hello Guys i am very new to java and i wanted to have a registeration form i almost get it but don't know i am doing something wrong. Here is my method..

```js
private void RegisterBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
  try {
    final String host = "abc";
    final String user = "abc";
    final String pwd = "abc";

    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(host, user, pwd);

    statement = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
      ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
    String userName = txt_registerUsername.getText();
    String address = txt_registerAddress.getText();
    String phoneNo = txt_phoneNo.getText();
    String password = txt_registerPassword.getText();
    //final String select_query = "INSERT INTO Users ('username','address','phoneno','password') VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
    //rs = statement.executeQuery(select_query);
    //rs.next();
    PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(
      "INSERT INTO Users VALUES(?,?,?,?)");

    ps.setString(1, userName);
    ps.setString(2, address);
    ps.setString(3, phoneNo);
    ps.setString(4, password);

    int i = ps.executeUpdate();
    if (i > 0)
      System.out.print("You are successfully registered...");
    else {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry Try again Later");
    }

  } catch (SQLException ex) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry Something went wrong");
  }
}
```

The output here is the catch SQLException.
Thanks.

Comment: What is the content/error message from the `SQLException`?

Comment: I fixed it and posted an answer it was the problem with my setString and and i wasn't providing columns name. thanks  for lookiing into it

Answer (score 0):

You have not selected the database.
Additionally can you e.printStackTrace() , in your SQLException catch block.

Comment: } catch (SQLException ex) {  ex.printStackTrace();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry Something went wrong");
  }   <br/> tell me what do you see in the stack trace on your console.

Comment: Sorry But i cannat getting you as i said i am new to java

Comment: in your catch block - for SQLException - add a line  before JOption.... , ex.printStackTrace();    once you add the line and run the program again. if you get an exception then on your console you will see a exception log.  paste the log here.

Comment: Saying that the number of values assigned is not the same as the number of specified or implied columns.

Comment: ps.setString(0, userName);
    ps.setString(1, address);
    ps.setString(2, phoneNo);
    ps.setString(3, password);   try this

Comment: well i set that number according to my column position in db it that what it is?

Comment: for your info i  have 5 columns including userId, username,address,phoneNo,password in this squence...

Comment: sorry about that, how many columns you have in Users table. I think some has suggested explicitly specifying column name. try that.

Comment: userId is auto increment ?

Comment: yup userId is auto incremented

Comment: PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Users (username,address,phoneno,password) VALUES(?,?,?,?)");

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified the column names,try Changing this

```
INSERT INTO Users VALUES(?,?,?,?)
```

back to the commented query above i.e. this

```
INSERT INTO Users ('username','address','phoneno','password') VALUES(?,?,?,?)
```

give this a try.

Comment: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "\'username\'" at line 1, column 19. ??

Comment: Don't put the column names in single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

updateString() and i wasn't providing columns names correctly here is how did it work for me...

```js
try {
  String username = txt_registerUsername.getText();
  String address = txt_registerAddress.getText();
  String phoneno = txt_phoneNo.getText();
  int pass = Integer.parseInt(txt_registerPassword.getText());

  rs.moveToInsertRow();

  rs.updateString("username", username);
  rs.updateString("address", address);
  rs.updateString("phoneno", phoneno);
  rs.updateInt("password", pass);

  rs.insertRow();

  statement.close();
  rs.close();
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Registeration.this, "New Record Added");
  connectDB();

} catch (SQLException ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry Something went wrong");
}
```